# How to prevent another app from moving (MS Excel 2010) in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I need my app to open Excel 2010 and position it in a specific area of my application.
I also need Excel to be unresizable, unmovable and eliminate all menu interactions (Close, maximize, minimize)

I've found a solution for almost everything, APART from making it unmovable.
I tried to use SetWindowPos and set the SWP_NOMOVE flag and a few other flags but I got no success at all.

--Specifications: I'm using WPF C#.NET 4.0 and MS Excel 2010.

--Below is the method I've come with. Everything work as expected apart from SetWindowPos (it doesn't have any effect at all)

```
public static void StartExcel(string p_processArguments, int p_x, int p_y, int p_height, int p_width,
                                  bool p_startMin = true, bool p_setForeground = true, bool p_useShell = true,
                                  bool p_waitInput = true, bool p_setNewStyles = true, bool p_removeMenu = true)
    {
        //Make sure there is no excel opened (Kill them all -  if any)
        CloseAllExcelProcesses(true);

        //Make the most basic validations and required info.           
        if (!ValidateProcessArgument(p_processArguments))
            throw new Exception("Process' argument is invalid or incorrectly setted. " + p_processArguments);

        ProcessStartInfo psiApp = new ProcessStartInfo("excel", p_processArguments);
        if (p_useShell)
            psiApp.UseShellExecute = true;
        else
            psiApp.UseShellExecute = false;

        if (p_startMin)
            psiApp.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        Process pApp = Process.Start(psiApp);
        if (p_waitInput)
            pApp.WaitForInputIdle();

        //Wait for the app to receive the window handle(ID) max limit of 3sec.
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        if (pApp.MainWindowHandle != (IntPtr)0)
        {
            if (p_startMin) //Now restore its state
                Win32Import.ShowWindow(pApp.MainWindowHandle, WindowShowStyle.ShowNormal);

            //Set Foreground
            if (p_setForeground)
                Win32Import.SetForegroundWindow(pApp.MainWindowHandle);

            if (p_setNewStyles)
            {
                //Make it an Overlapped Window (Which has no size border, title bar and etc).
                int style = Win32Import.GetWindowLong(pApp.MainWindowHandle, Win32Import.GWL_STYLE);
                Win32Import.SetWindowLong(pApp.MainWindowHandle, Win32Import.GWL_STYLE, (uint)(style & ~Win32.WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW));

                //NOT WORKING - Apply some flags, to make it unmovable.
                Win32Import.SetWindowPos(pApp.MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Win32.SWP.NOMOVE);
                Win32Import.UpdateWindow(pApp.MainWindowHandle);
            }

            if (p_removeMenu)
            {                    
                //Get the app original menu.
                IntPtr hMenu = Win32Import.GetSystemMenu(pApp.MainWindowHandle, false);
                //Get the amount of menu the app has.
                int count = Win32Import.GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);

                //Remove all existing main menus.
                for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    Win32Import.RemoveMenu(hMenu, i, (Win32Import.MF_BYPOSITION | Win32Import.MF_REMOVE));

                //Force a redraw.
                Win32Import.DrawMenuBar(pApp.MainWindowHandle);
            }

            //Move the window to the specified location and size (set new position).                
            Win32Import.MoveWindow(pApp.MainWindowHandle, p_x, p_y, p_width, p_height, true);                
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("StartEmbeddedApp - Couldn't get the embedded app handle.");
        }
    }
```

I've also come up with a few different ideas such as interceping Excel WM_Message (perhaps by using HWNDSource). Any idea not too complicated to achieve this is welcome!

Thanks in advance,
Luís.

Comment: On an unrelated note there is [`IntPtr.Zero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero.aspx).

Comment: Yuck. Wouldn't something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati) be far simpler (even if I suspect that is still more complicated than necessary)?

Comment: hvd, I've seen the article you mentioned before. However, it doesn't work anymore. I've just downloaded it and tried with MS Excel 2010. The excel is never captured and placed inside. It just opens normally outside the box.

Comment: @Luishg That depends on the configuration, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059/en-us) for configuring Excel files to open outside of the browser, you can do the reverse to open Excel files in the browser. (I can confirm it's possible with Excel 2013.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken about the SWP_NOMOVE parameter. That parameter does not mean that the window will not be movable, it just means that the x,y parameters will be ignored during that specific call to the method SetWindowPos. The goal of that flag is to use the function SetWindowPos for changing the size of the target window without changing its position.

[From SetWindowPos in MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx)

**SWP_NOMOVE**
0x0002
Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).

Something that you could try is to create a custom window on your application that handles all messages related to size and position (examples:WM_SIZE, WM_SIZING, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, etc) to prevent modifications, then set your excel window as a child window of your custom window.

You could also try [to  just remove the title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825528/removing-the-title-bar-of-external-application-using-c-sharp)

Comment: One bruce force approach would be continously poll and force the user's application is only window that has focus.

Comment: Ramhound, unfortunately that is not an option. Excel needs focus. THe user can interacct with its workbook, sheet, save and etc. But the user can not be able to move it!