# Open notepad in WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

You can open Notepad in WinForm with this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
            p.WaitForInputIdle(); // Allow the process to open it's window
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
        }
    }
```

In WPF `this.handle` is not recognized. What is the WPF version of this.Handle?

And how can you open Notepad in full screen without the close button's in a WPF screen?

Comment: WPF version is `new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle` where `this` is instance of WPF `Window`.

Comment: @Evk indeed thats it, but hmm guess it wont work in WPF.. notepad opens out of the wpf windows.

Comment: For the appended question, you can refer to [Removing the Title bar of external application using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825528/removing-the-title-bar-of-external-application-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Have you achieve what you want? @user7849697

Answer (score 5):

You can get the handle of a WPF window using `WindowInteropHelper` while the widow has `Loaded` or `SourceInitialized`. In the constructor method, the handle has not yet been created, it returns a handle of zero. Just have a try:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        p.WaitForInputIdle(); // Allow the process to open it's window
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    };
}
```

Alternatively,

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

    Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    p.WaitForInputIdle(); // Allow the process to open it's window
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
}
```