# Taskpane loosing focus when undocked

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto

I have a C# VSTO Word addin with simple taskpane in which I am loading a notepad. When the taskpane is docked on the right i can type in the notepad and perform any operation flawlessly. However, when the taskpane is floating (undocked) I am experiencing two issues which are (a) word instance steals the focus and i cannot type anymore in the notepad, (b) when i click in the notepad the taskpane gets hidden, on second click it appears. When i dock taskpane back in any position the focus is again on the notepad. To embed the notepad i used following post [Removing the Title bar of external application using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825528/removing-the-title-bar-of-external-application-using-c-sharp). Does anybody experienced anything similar before?

Comment: I don't have any ideas how to fix your problem, but I'm curious about what you're doing. Are you taking an instance of Notepad.exe and embedding it into the task pane so only the editor part is showing?

Comment: yes, but notepad is just an example